# Multiple problems: Wine Counter Strike freezes AND Transfer of big files stucks when transferred to PEN DRIVE

Tags: usb, wine, usb-drive, freeze

I have been having some problems since many days:

1. When I play counter strike, and if I press the UP or DOWN key of *VOLUME*, the game hangs. It freezes. The music in the background still plays, and the cursor also moves, but the whole laptop freezes

   I reinstalled WINE and installed the game, but no use.. **:(**
2. When I transfer big files like movies to a pen drive, it transfers very fast, but at the last moment it freezes, when there is still 4 to 5 Mbs of data left to transfer.

   I used all my usb ports, but it freezes at all ports. Also, I used different pen drives, but no use.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: 1) Are you using proprietary graphics drivers or the ones that came preinstalled with the system? Have you set Counter-Strike to OpenGL or DirectX mode in the graphic settings? Why aren't you using the native Linux version of CS published by Valve?

Comment: Second that. Steam Linux has support for CS. Might be better off using that for Linux supported games and wine for the non Linux ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue 1**: As already mentioned in the comments, use the native version of Counter Strike. (It should be in your Steam games library already!)

**Issue 2**: You've probable got [MLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-level_cell) pen drives that are really slow, so Ubuntu copies the data to the cache and then doesn't freeze, but *keeps writing from the cache* to the pen drive until it's finished.

If you want fast pen drive performance, you should buy [SLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-level_cell#Single-level_cell) ones...  (they're 2-4 times more expensive then the cheap ones though, but they last longer)

**Issue 3**: You should write one question per issue because no one knows everything about Ubuntu (for the record: nor do I) and the more issues in one question, the less likely you are of finding a solution to your issues.

Comment: And as you're a reputation 3 user: don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, therefore "accepting" the answer, which is better then saying "thank you" as both of our reputations will go up!  ;-)